# how to get new link after String Replace

Tags: javascript

can you help me

I want the results of the code is new url with hyperlink ( new.url, not old.url )

old.url/example.html to => new.url/example.html

i have javascript code like this,

```
<p id="crot"></p>



var currentURL=location.href;
var str = currentURL;
var res = str.replace("old.url", "new.url");
var result = res.link("");
document.getElementById("crot").innerHTML = result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a link wrap it in an anchor tag:

```js
var currentURL = location.href;
var currentURL = "http://old.url/example"; // for testing
var str = currentURL;
var result = str.replace("old.url", "new.url");
var link = "<a href='"+result+"'>"+result+"</a>";
// add link
document.getElementById("crot").innerHTML = link;
```

```html
<p id="crot"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<a id="crot">click here</a>
<script>
var currentURL = location.href;
var result = currentURL.replace("old.url", "new.url");
document.getElementById("crot").href = result;
</script>
```

`String.replace()` returns a string. You can just look at that directly. I don't know what you were trying to achieve with `res.link()`. There's no `link` method of strings.

Comment: He said he wants to create a hyperlink with the new URL.

Answer (score 0):

Just interpolate the URL into a `<a>` tag.

```
var result = `<a href="${res}">Click here</a>`;
document.getElementById("crot").innerHTML = result;
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this question correctly, use URL built-in module.

```
var url = new URL(currentURL);
url.host = 'new.hostname:8080';
document.getElementById("crot").innerHTML = url.href.link("");
```

check this js fiddle. (https://jsfiddle.net/hentleman/x4sw8kut/2/)